# Automatic invocation of Bean Validator for @Valid outside of Spring MVC

Tags: spring, bean-validation

Simple scenario:-

In a Spring 4 app the following @Valid gets triggered when I make a REST call but not when I make an API call. The docs talks about it but does not state how to do it the way I want.

```
@RequestMapping(name="/something")
public Entity save(@Valid Entity e){ return repo.save(e);}
```

Without writing any custom AOP code to achieve this myself etc. how do I get bean validation @Valid triggered in Spring ? Looking for any Spring or Hibernate configuration that will turn this on for simple API calls.

Example: When I bundle my component as a maven I would like to get my beans validated irrespective of whether they run in a web context or outside , say Spring Batch or just JUnit Tests. 
And when I bundle this jar in a web app I definitely don't want this executed twice.

Comment: AOP would do that for you, but you don't want…

Comment: No reason to avoid AOP. Just asking if there any convention/configuration. I will update the question a bit to clarify.

Comment: Hibernate is a different story. AFAIR there is something like a hibernate interceptor which validates entities regardless of `@Valid` if a validation provider is in the class path. But this happens during `persist()`.

Comment: Yup i.e. if we use Hibernate as a JPA provider instead of just as a provider for Bean Validator. +1 for stating that aspect though.

Comment: take a look at the 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor'. This post-processor  will add an AOP advice  for validating method parameters through the 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor', results. How to disable the method validation in the REST stack, to not do it twice' depends on how you have configured your application.